# No DBus signal available for Wake event in linux

Tags: ubuntu, event-handling, dbus

I wanted to perform some task in my application, as soon as the application wakes from sleep mode. To do that I wanted to detect the wake event in my application.
In the '**org.freeDesktop.login1**' interface, there is a signal '**PrepareForSleep**' available to detect the sleep event, however, there is no counterpart DBus signal available to detect the wake event. Either it is not available or I m not able to find the signal.
Can someone help me?